# Javascript code to manipulate dijit editor body get element by id

Tags: javascript, html, dijit.form

I have a problem, because I do not know how to change input field which looks like that in inspect element in Firefox. This is the part of website I would like to change from bookmark in javascript. When I input text to the field in code text appears just befire

```
<body id="dijitEditorBody" onload="frameElement._loadFunc(window,document)" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">HERE</body>
```

Function like that does not work:

```
document.getElementById('dijitEditorBody').innerHTML+= "new content";
```

Firefox can not find that id.

Answer (score 0):

dijit editor has many events like onClick, onChange etc...
you need to register for an event and then you should be able to change the value like

```
function:changeEditorValue(){
dijit.byId("editor id").set("value","new value");
}
```

Hope this helps